# Two request parameter in struts2 "redirect-action" result type

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-config

In the Below code,

```
<result type="redirectAction" name="success">
                <param name="actionName">
                    loadManagePrdtprty{1}?prtycrnid=${prtCrnId}&exitWindow=${exitWindow}
                </param>
            </result>
```

application is not getting start..What will be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that

> loadManagePrdtprty{1}?prtycrnid=${prtCrnId}&exitWindow=${exitWindow}

is your Action's name. You can look up on how o use redirectAction here : http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/post_and_redirect

Comment: I gave no example! I told you that the value you give for "action name" contains parameters and that you should read the article I linked on how that works.